# Run interactive Powershell in Windows Azure Container Instance

Tags: azure, docker, powershell, azure-container-instances, server-core

I can create a container group with:

```
az container create --os-type windows --resource-group dev --name win-sandbox --image mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:1809
```

Then running ⬇️ it just exits immediately, but I would like an interactive Powershell prompt.

```
az container exec -g dev --name win-sandbox --exec-command "powershell.exe"
```

---

This is consistent with omitting `-it` from a `docker run`, but there is no such option for `az container exec`.

How do I get an interactive Powershell prompt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I get an interactive Powershell prompt?

As per the [Azure documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/container?view=azure-cli-latest#az_container_exec) , currently `az container exec` to open & execute in interactive mode not supported for windows machines.

`az container exec` Execute a command from within a running container of a container group. The most common use case is to open an interactive bash shell.

Comment: How awkward. I've [suggested feedback is added](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/20827) to `az container`.